# Select from one table but filtering other two

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i've got this database:

```
 book
| idBook | name     |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |Book#1    |

category
| idCateg| category |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |Adventures|
|      2 |Science F.|

book_categ
| id     | idBook | idCateg  |   DATA |
|--------|--------|----------|--------|
|   1    |      1 |       1  | (null) |
|   2    |      1 |       2  | (null) |
```

I'm trying to select only the books which are in category 1 AND category 2 something like this

```
SELECT book.* FROM book,book_categ
WHERE book_categ.idCateg = 1 AND book_categ.idCateg = 2
```

Obviously, this giving 0 results becouse each row has only one idCateg it does work width OR but the results are not what I need. I've also tried to use a join, but I just can't get the results I expect.
Here it's the SQLFiddle of my current project, with my current DB, the data at the begining is just a sample. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e6bc/49)
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: ...I'm a little concerned over the `DATA` column.  What are you planning on putting in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using EXISTS:

```
select *
  from book b
 where exists (select 'x'
          from book_categ x
         where x.idbook = b.idbook
           and x.idcateg = 1)
   and exists (select 'x'
          from book_categ x
         where x.idbook = b.idbook
           and x.idcateg = 2)
```

Solution using join with an inline view:

```
select *
  from book b
  join (select idbook
          from book_categ
         where idcateg in (1, 2)
         group by idbook
        having count(*) = 2) x
    on b.idbook = x.idbook
```

Comment: Both method worked as expected. Considering that I will match more than 2 categories should I use the soulution using a join ?

Comment: @LCH that would probably be easiest in your case, if it's always just a matter of getting books that are associated with N categories, and other variables aren't at play

Comment: For the first query Note that the correlated subqueries in the EXISTS predicates will get executed for each row in the outer query; it's not  an issue for small sets, but for increasing larger sets, this can be a performance issue. A JOIN operation will typically give better performance.  The second query depends on  `(idbook,idcateg)` being unique, where the first query doesn't have that as a requirement.

Comment: I would assume they are unique given the likely purpose of the book_categ table.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `ALL` instead of `IN` (if you only want values that match all criteria to be returned):

```
SELECT book.*
FROM book, book_categ
WHERE book_categ.idCateg = ALL(1 , 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the result is to do join to the book_categ table twice, something like

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM book b 
  JOIN book_categ c1
    ON c1.book_id = b.id
   AND c1.idCateg = 1
  JOIN book_categ c2
    ON c2.book_id = b.id
   AND c2.idCateg = 2
```

This assumes that `(book_id, idCateg)` is constrained to be unique in the `book_categ` table. If it isn't unique, then this query can return duplicate rows.  Adding a GROUP BY clause or the DISTINCT keyword will eliminate any generated duplicates.

There are several other queries that can get generate the same result.

For example, another approach to finding book_id that are in two categories is to get all the rows with idCateg values of 1 or 2, and then GROUP BY book_id and get a count of DISTINCT values...

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM book b 
  JOIN ( SELECT d.book_id
           FROM book_categ d
          WHERE d.idCateg IN (1,2)
          GROUP BY d.book_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.idCateg) = 2 
       ) c
   ON c.book_id = b.id
```